# Google Drive API children.list

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to make javascript code to list the names of all the files in the root directory of Google Drive.  FYI: I'm new to javascript.

For the first function, I copied code from https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list .

The next two functions are my own code.  My results is just a bunch of "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]".  This output matches the number of files I have in the root folder of my Google Drive.  However, I want the file names or id's, but I can't seem to get anything besides "[object Object]".

I tried changing the  "resp.items" to "resp.kind" or "resp.selflink" but then I just get "undefined".  Anyone know how to get any specific information on the files?  In case it matters, scope is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".

```
function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, callback) {
  var retrievePageOfChildren = function(request, result) {
    request.execute(function(resp) {
      result = result.concat(resp.items);
      var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
      if (nextPageToken) {
        request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
          'folderId' : folderId,
          'pageToken': nextPageToken
        });
        retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
      } else {
        callback(result);
      }
    });
  }
  var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
      'folderId' : folderId
    });
  retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
}



function printToOutdiv (result){document.getElementById("outdiv").innerHTML=result;}

function GetFilesButton (){
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {retrieveAllFilesInFolder('root',printToOutdiv);} );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you are getting is an array of objects that you can access by index, as in `result[0]`, `result[1]`, and so on.

Once you get a reference to one of those objects, you can access its properties (e.g. the id) as in `result[0].id`.

Comment: For some reason, I was not successful with the result(0).id approach.  However, I tried a for loop using "resp.items[i].id" just before the callback and it got what I needed.  Thanks for your help, Claudio.