# Getting filenames from gapi.client.drive.children.list in google drive javascript api

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I'm trying get the list of files on a public google drive folder.
I've successfully authenticated and do see the files but my resulting children array consists of child objects that only has the fields `kind` and `id`.
is it possible to get any other fields like `title`,`selfLink` or `childLink` from the objects?

If I run the same code with replacing `children.list` with `files.list` then I do get the `title` field but thats just for the files in my google drive, not the public folder I want. I've went through the [children resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children#resource) and the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource) but cannot figure if it is even possible to get any metadata from a children array

I'm using google example code, with minimum changes,

```
        function retrieveAllFilesInFolder(folderId, query, callback) {
            var retrievePageOfChildren = function(request, result) {
                request.execute(function(resp) {
                    result = result.concat(resp.items);
                    var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
                    if (nextPageToken) {
                        request = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
                            'folderId' : folderId,
                            'pageToken': nextPageToken
                        });
                        retrievePageOfChildren(request, result);
                    } else {
                        callback(result);
                    }
                });
            }
            var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.children.list({
                'folderId' : folderId,
                'q' : query
            });
            retrievePageOfChildren(initialRequest, []);
        }
```

I'm new to both javascript and stackoverflow so pardon if I missed something.
thanks.
[related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057047/google-drive-api-children-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll answer it myself,
I havent found a way to get the `title`,`selfLink` or `childLink` directly from `gapi.client.drive.children.list` request. I decide to get the ids from `children.list` and use `gapi.client.drive.files.get` request with those ids to get the necessary meta data, as follows.

```
        function getMetaData(fileId) {
            var request = gapi.client.drive.files.get({
                'fileId': fileId
            });
            request.execute(function(resp) {
                dataArray.push(resp)
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve files (including all meta info) from underneath a certain folder, you can still use drive.files.list(),  thereby passing the folder id as a query parameter. Here's an example:

```
    function retrieveAllFiles(callback) {
    var retrievePageOfFiles = function (request, result) {
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            result = result.concat(resp.items);
            var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
            if (nextPageToken) {
                request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                    'pageToken': nextPageToken
                });
                retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
            } else {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    };

    var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        q : "'<FOLDER_ID_HERE>' in parents"
    });
    retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
}
```

More info on search params: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters

Comment: did you find how to search like this? i am getting this error > `GET https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=fullText%20%3D%20%27foldeName%27 400 (Bad Request)`

Comment: Something to do with a typo: foldeName?